# Issue on mobile devices showing hidden Navbar menu on swiping

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an issue with the navbar component in mobile devices. I've been following a react youtube [tutorial](https://github.com/fireclint/real-estate-react/blob/main/src/components/navbar/Navbar.css) and I have noticed that on mobile devices if I swipe to the left the navbar menu appears to be hidden in the right part of the screen, like if the screen is extended with the size of the menu. Moreover, when I open the menu and then I swipe I have the same issue, the screen is extended to the right the same size as the menu. I tried to solve it using the overflow-x: hidden; and transform: translateX but it does not work.

Here you can find an example. https://jsfiddle.net/jbacardit/5q7083hg/14/

How could avoid showing the hidden menu on the right on swiping to the left?

The css file

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.navbar .container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding:1rem;
}

.navbar span {
    color: #5651e5;
}

.navbar .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
}

.navbar li {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.navbar .icon {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width:940px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar .nav-menu {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        top: 90px;
        right: -100%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255, .98);
        transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .navbar .active {
        right: 0;
    }

    .navbar .nav-menu li a {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

This is the jsx file:

```
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick((prevState) => !prevState);

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div className="container">
        <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu hideMe'}>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div className="hamburger" onClick={handleClick}>
        {click ? (<i className="icon" >Click here</i>) : (<i className="icon">Swipe right =====></i>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Its because the menu is `position:absolute`. you should apply `position:relative` to a parent element along with  `overflow-x:hidden`